# How can I get a css position change to take effect during a JQuery UI Draggable element's start event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, draggable, redraw

I have an odd situation in which I need to modify the position of a draggable element as soon as the user starts dragging it. So, during the draggable element's start event handler, I'm trying to set the position. It doesn't respond to the position change unless - and this is weird - I do something to cause a javascript error after I change the position. Here's an example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Drag reposition test</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/css_browser_selector.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="development-bundle/ui/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.js"></script> <!-- Includes JQuery UI Draggable. -->

<style type="text/css">
    #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $("#initialdragger").draggable({    
        start: function(e, ui) {
            $('#initialdragger').css('top', 400);
            x = y; // Javascript error, which weirdly causes a redraw.
        }
    });     
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="initialdragger" class="ui-widget-content" style="border-width: 1px; border-color: black; background-color: orange; width: 300px">
    <p>Drag me around</p>       
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I legitimately cause a redraw to happen in this context? JQuery's hide() and show() don't work and neither do [these methods](http://ajaxian.com/archives/forcing-a-ui-redraw-from-javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think binding a mousedown event will get you what you want

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#initialdragger").draggable();
        $('#initialdragger').bind("mousedown", function(e) {
            $(this).css('top', 400);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That's what I needed. I also needed it to only happen the first time, so tossing in an unbind call took care of that.